Why Mybatis updates fail
Here is the mapper method:
int updateAnchorIndexByBookId(Map<String, Object> params);
and here is the xml:
<update id="updateAnchorIndexByBookId" parameterType="map">
        UPDATE ad_novel_chapter_info
        SET update_time = #{updateTime},
        is_free =
        CASE
        WHEN chapter_index <![CDATA[ < ]]> #{anchorIndex} THEN 1
        ELSE 0
        END
        WHERE book_id = #{bookId}
    </update>

and here is the actual sql:
==>  Preparing: UPDATE ad_novel_chapter_info SET update_time = ?, is_free = CASE WHEN chapter_index < ? THEN 1 ELSE 0 END WHERE book_id = ? ==> Parameters: 1724333706334(Long), 90(Integer), 9603(Long) <==    Updates: 0 
but it doesn't work.(no rows are updated)
I try to run this sql in mysql, it works.
But it doesn't work in Mybatis.
What's wrong?

When you say: but it doesn't work, I assume you mean that no rows are updated in [database] table ad_novel_chapter_info. If my assumption is correct, then obviously the value for book_id does not exist in the table. Can you not verify that?

Thank you for your reply. Yes, no rows are updated. I can confirm that the book_id does exist, and if I run the sql in Navicat, the records are updated. So I'm puzzled why it can be executed in navicat but not in the code.

@dreamck I don't see any obvious mistake. If the issue reproduces without mybatis-plus, create and share a small repro project on your GitHub repo and I will take a look (I know nothing about mybatis-plus). Here are some project templates and examples.
